# How to set 2D Text position same to all devices in Spark AR

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

I have some problems when I try to test my filter to 2 Devices, iPhone and Android. when I test on the iPhone, the position of text contains date and time is good in the near bottom left like this [image]. But when I test on an Android device, the text position is too far up like this [image].

Is there a way to fix the position of 2D text for all devices?
here is my project
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your magic button is **pinning to bottom**.
Maybe you also need to use **left pinning**.

Also switch to resizableWindow option, instead of an actual device, this way you can check any possible aspect ratios! (top left corner of a screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping, the position already fix after rearrange in Resizable Window option.